# .net: How to parse a date with this format: 08 Feb 2011 06:46

Tags: .net, datetime

How do I use DateTime.Parse to parse a datetime with the following format:

`08 Feb 2011 06:46`

In response to the answer I've received so far, I tried the following:

```
item.ServerDate = DateTime.ParseExact
                ("08 Feb 2011 06:46", "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I still get the exception: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

UPDATE: The following code works without the hour and minute:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("08 Feb 2011","dd MMM yyyy",null)
```

Comment: Are we to assume that 06:46 is military time?

Comment: I think it should work if you replace "Mmm" with "MMM".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DateTime.ParseExact("08 Feb 2011 06:46", "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm", 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In your question's sample code, you forgot to capitalize all of the month "M"s.

#### Edit

As Anton points out, the "H"s also need to be capitalized to use military time.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("08 Feb 2011 13:46", "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm", 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

The above code works for me. I can't imagine why you'd get an error on the same code, when we're specifying the culture. Can you double-check your code and inputs?

Comment: Thanks.  My code is doing something really weird.  Your code works.  However, in my *real* code, I pass in a variable holding the string literal and somehow that makes the difference between getting the date and not getting the date.

Comment: @Rice Flour Cookies: That is odd. What does the variable's value look like when you step through the code with the debugger? Is it possible that a DLL isn't getting updated or something?

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime.ParseExact` might work for you:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

```
"hh": The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12.
"HH": The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23.
```

and

> In the .NET Framework 4, the
>   ParseExact method throws a
>   FormatException if the string to be
>   parsed contains an hour component and
>   an AM/PM designator that are not in
>   agreement. In the .NET Framework 3.5
>   and earlier versions, the AM/PM
>   designator is ignored.

So try replacing `"hh"` by `"HH"` in your format specifier, ie try `"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"`