# Convert Date to "dd-MMM-yyyy" format c#

Tags: c#-3.0

Guys i am unable to convert datetime to "dd-MMM-yyyy" format. My code is given below:

```
TreeNode tn = new TreeNode(dr["pBillDate"].ToString());       // Here i am getting both date and time.
```

I need to convert it as "20-Mar-2013".

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: If its working (as mentioned below) then you might want to accept the answer that provided you the solution.

Comment: old question but I search for parse a "dd MMM yyyy" string to date, and on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330909/net-how-to-parse-a-date-with-this-format-08-feb-2011-0646 post, a solution says that have to use DateTime.ParseExact to parse any date string telling what format like to parse, then can convert as the answer on this post says with tostring("dd mm etc....") again to another string format

Answer (score 55):

Try this code:

```
string formattedDate = YourDate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

It will format to like:

```
12 Nov 2012
```

Comment: Why this answer is not accepted as correct? This help others.

Answer (score 9):

The following couple examples should work:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["pBillDate"]);

TreeNode tn = new TreeNode(String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", dt));
```

or

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["pBillDate"]);

TreeNode tn = new TreeNode(dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 7):

```
DateTime StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datepicker.Text);
string Date = StartDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Comment: Some explanation would help.

Answer (score 1):

try Following

```
    TreeNode tn = new TreeNode(dr["pBillDate"].ToShortDateString());
```

it can convert DateTime to Date

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Find below code:

`DateTime todayDay = DateTime.Today.ToString();`

It will provide you with `dd-MMM-yyyy` format.

Comment: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'"