# Convert UK date format to American

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, date-format

I have a JQuery date picker which puts the date into a textbox in format DD/MM/YYYY.

I am trying to store this in SQL Server 2008 which needs to accept the date as MM/DD/YYYY, how should I format the date to get this to work correctly?

This is the code to add a my parameter to the query, which causes an error as the day and the month are the wrong way round

```
 TextBox fixtureDateTextBox = (TextBox)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolderMenu").FindControl("datepicker");
 SqlParameter fixtureDateParam = new SqlParameter("@fixtureDate", fixtureDateTextBox.Text);
```

Comment: Check this out, should be what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15547264/2171266

Comment: Matt look up using `SqlParameters.AddWithValue()` method use that opposed to SqlParameter also pass in values to your parameters as variables not as clear or hard coded text `Avoind  SQL Injection`

Answer (score 4):

Never, **ever** directly insert input text into a parameter as you're doing - it's the root cause of too many security vulnerabilities and holes. Parse the input into a `DateTimeOffset` object first (you can also use `DateTime`, but the Offset is better in general to use) by calling `DateTimeOffset.Parse(...)`, then you can simply add it as a parameter without modifying it.

EDIT: I re-read your question, and realized that while the above isn't wrong, it does miss some important things that address your question. See [this](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#alt-field) for how to configure the date picker to display an alternate date format from what it stores in an alternate field:

EDIT 2:
You'll want to parse your `DateTime` object using the overload which allows you to pass in an `IFormatProvider` instance.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx for an example of how to do what you're looking to do. Otherwise, `DateTime.Parse('13/3/2013')` will fail due to unrecognized format.

`DateTime.Parse('13/3/2013', new CultureInfo("en-GB").DateTimeFormat)` is what you want to do with the input box.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other folks that you should be able to configure the JQuery picker format to begin with, but if you can't, this *should* do the trick:

```
TextBox fixtureDateTextBox = (TextBox)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolderMenu").FindControl("datepicker");
DateTime fixtureDate = DateTime.Parse(fixtureDateTextBox.Text, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
SqlParameter fixtureDateParam = new SqlParameter("@fixtureDate", fixtureDate.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: yours is a robust solution because it doesn't assume anything about the CurrentUICulture when calling ToString on that date

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TextBox fixtureDateTextBox = (TextBox)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolderMenu").FindControl("datepicker");
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(fixtureDateTextBox.Text);
SqlParameter fixtureDateParam = new SqlParameter("@fixtureDate", date);
```

Comment: that will fail if your CultureInfo is anything but `en-UK` (or a culture info that follows that calendar date format convention)

Answer (score 0):

Add in the namespaces section: `using System.Globalization;`

then parse your input date as follows:

```
string DB_Date = (DateTime.Parse(fixtureDateTextBox.Text)).ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: That will still fail if the CurrentCulture isn't one that supports that date format style

Answer (score -1):

```
  DateTime UKDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datepicker.Text);<br>
  string usDate= UKDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");<br>
  SqlParameter fixtureDateParam = new SqlParameter("@fixtureDate", usDate);
```