# CONVERT date format from mm-dd-yyyy to dd-mmm-yyyy in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I am trying insert asp.net form field values to oracle database table. I have a date field which is in "MM-DD-YYYY" format. I need to add that date to oracle table. So i am trying to convert that date format to "DD-MMM-YYYY" format. But i am getting the following error.

code:

```
var creation_date = DateTime.ParseExact(CreationDateTextBox.Text, "DD-MMM-YYYY",null);
```

Text box value is: 12-12-2013.(No time)
i am getting error like "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Date to "dd-MMM-yyyy" format c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546953/convert-date-to-dd-mmm-yyyy-format-c-sharp)

Comment: have you tried to check links on internet???

Comment: You've been Skeet'd. :)

Comment: try `DateTime.ParseExact("12-dec-2013", "dd-MMM-yyyy",null)`

Comment: A [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.aspx) has no format. It's basically a fancy `Int64` counting ticks. So you cannot "convert" a `DateTime` from one format to another. You *can* "convert" (i.e. parse) a `String` to get a `DateTime`. But to do that, you need to tell the parse method the format of the `String` you're parsing *from*. In this case: `"MM-dd-yyyy"`. Then, if you want to *display* that abstract number of ticks, you convert it back to the human readable form you like: `date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")`.  But putting it into a DB should *not* require that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might help :)

```
String myString = "12-30-2014"; // get value from text field
DateTime myDateTime = new DateTime();
myDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(myString, "MM-dd-yyyy",null);
String myString_new = myDateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); // add myString_new to oracle
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to *parse* the date using `MM-dd-yyyy` but then you shouldn't need to *format* it at all. Just pass it to the database *as a `DateTime`* using parameterized SQL.

```
DateTime creationDate;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(CreationDateTextBox.Text, "MM-dd-yyyy",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,
                           out creationDate))
{
    // Use creationDate within a database command, but *don't* convert it
    // back to a string.
}
else
{
    // Handle invalid input
}
```

Avoid string conversions wherever you can. Indeed, ideally use a date/time picker of some description rather than just a text field - that will give users a better experience and reduce the risk of poor conversions.

Also note that whenever you want to use custom string conversions (parsing or formatting) you should read the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - `YYYY` and `DD` aren't valid format specifiers.

Comment: The OP appears to be doing day month year, rather than month day year, though with 12-12-2013 its hard to tell for sure.

Comment: @paqogomez: No, "I have a date field which is in "MM-DD-YYYY" format." (And look at the title.) They've got it the wrong way round in their current code.

Comment: I should never have doubted.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(CreationDateTextBox.Text);
var creation_date=String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", dt)
```

OR try as

```
 dt.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

Comment: Why would you use a compound string format rather than just calling `dt.ToString("...")`? Not that I think using a format is a good idea anyway...

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree with you but As per my knowledge, You can not print `MMM` using DateTime

Comment: You absolutely can, but that's completely orthogonal to using `ToString` vs `String.Format` - and again, I wouldn't format the value at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have three M for the month, which is used for month names. Just use two M.

Comment: @SandeepReddyK. its not about the format that you need, its about the format that you have in the text box.  A datetime object doesnt have a format, you give it one when you print it out.  Roland's answer is correct.

Comment: While the OP *does* need two Ms, they also need to change their format in other ways - `DD` and `YYYY` aren't valid custom format specifiers, and the ordering is incorrect for the specified input format. Then the OP has asked with how to *format* the result as well, which this answer doesn't mention.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private DateTime ConvertToDateTime(string strDateTime)
    {
        DateTime dtFinaldate; string sDateTime;
        try { dtFinaldate = Convert.ToDateTime(strDateTime); }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string[] sDate = strDateTime.Split('/');
            sDateTime = sDate[1] + '/' + sDate[0] + '/' + sDate[2];
            dtFinaldate = Convert.ToDateTime(sDateTime);
        }
        return dtFinaldate;
    }
```