# DateTime.TryParseExact Converting "15" hours to 3 PM

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a function that for demo purposes looks like such:

```
public static bool doSomething (int year, int month, int date, int hour, int minute, int second)
{
        string dateFormat = "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss";
        string hourstring = hour < 10 ? string.Format("{0}0", hour) : hour.ToString();
        string minuteString = minute < 10 ? string.Format("0{0}", minute) : minute.ToString();
        string secondString = second < 10 ? string.Format("0{0}", second) : second.ToString();

        var dateString = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2} {3}:{4}:{5}", month, date, year, hourString, minuteString, secondString);

        DateTime testDate = new DateTime();

        bool test = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out testDate);

        return test;
}
```

I've tried calling my funciton as `doSomething(2016, 1, 1, 15, 0, 0)`

So Im trying to get my function to return true while parsing the date January 1st, 2016 3:00:00 PM.
But it always returns false.

Is my dateFormat string incorrect? How can I get TryParseExact to interpret 15 hour as 3 PM?

Thanks

Comment: Does [capital "H" in the dateFormat make it use 24 hour time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5331077/424129)?

Comment: Turns it its captial "HH".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using lower case `hh` which is for 12 hours format and you are passing `15` which is for 24 hours format.

Use `HH` *(uppercase)* in your format.

```
string dateFormat = "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
```

For more see: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)